# flutter desktop app build faild with error MSB3073

Tags: flutter, dart

When I try to run a desktop application. It shows some error and the build is failed.

[This is the error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHlK0.png)
how to solve this problem,
anyone with a solution on how to handle this,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kv4sy.png)
The flutter doctor looks perfect. Then what was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest version of the SDK in Visual Studio
Then Open the Android Studio or VS Code
And run the below commands
flutter clean
flutter run